# How to make a drive read-only?

Tags: disk, ssd, readonly

how to make SSD drive read-only?

Linux, windows, and mac
and make a way to rewrite when the drive needs to update

Like rewrite CD / DVD
When boot from disk can not be modified
But as data disk on set system can be updated

Like CD dvd bluray disc

Comment: What are you hoping to protect against?

Comment: `hdparm -r 1 /dev/sd?`

Answer (score 3):

You can mount the disk partition as read-only:

```
mount -o ro /dev/sda1 /path/to/mountpoint
```

or you can set the read-only flag on the disk, disallowing write operations on the whole disk:

```
hdparm -r1 /dev/sda
```

I also remember that some old SSD USB sticks used to have a physical switch that disallowed writes entirely (I own one of these).

However, there is not a way to "make a way to rewrite when the drive needs to update". Either the disk is writable, or it isn't. You might accomplish what you want by setting the correct user permissions on the mount point; this is done at the OS level, so there is not a magic solution that works for both Linux, Windows, and MacOS.